# how can I write LIKE statement in rails for mongodb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

The search is working when I use whole words but I want also partial words to be recognized.

I have the form here:

```
= form_tag({}, method: :get) do
      = text_field_tag :query, query, class: 'form-input search__input', placeholder: t('.placeholder')
      - if query.nil?
        %span.search__icon.fa.fa-search{ aria: { hidden: 'true' } }
      - else
        = link_to more_path do
          %span.search__icon.text-success.fa.fa-times{ aria: { hidden: 'true' } }
```

controller:

```
  def set_query
    @query = params[:query]
  end


  def set_documents
    @documents = @folder ? @folder.documents : current_user.documents
    @documents = (params[:query] ? @documents.where(
      :$text => {:$search => params[:query]}
    ) : @documents).page(params[:page])
  end
```

I tried to add this in the controller to make it work as I want it:

```
@documents = Document.where('name LIKE ?', "%#{@query}%")
      end
```

but then I get the error:

```
wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)
```

How should I write this so that the search can work not only for whole words but also for partial words written.

Comment: Is `Document` an ApplicationRecord subclass?  The syntax you provided for the `like` matcher is not the cause of the `wrong number of arguments` error..  Where do you call `set_query`?  The `form_tag` doesn't look right.

Comment: @codenamev in this controller `before_action :set_query `

Comment: Where were you putting `@documents = Document.where('name LIKE ?', "%#{@query}%")`?

Comment: @muistooshort you're right! it is indeed mongodb, I should have

Comment: @codenamev where I defined set_query, but that's more like to show what I want to achieve since as someone suggested LIKE won't work in mongodb

Answer (score 1):

If you're using mongoid, you can use regular expressions in your `where`:

```
Document.where(name: /.*(#{@query})+.*/i)
```

Or try `any_of`:

```
Document.any_of(name: /.*(#{Regexp.escape(@query)}).*/i)
```

So your `set_documents` method should look something like:

```
def set_documents
  @documents = @folder ? @folder.documents : current_user.documents
  @documents = (params[:query] ? @documents.where(
    name: /.*#{@query}.*/i
  ) : @documents).page(params[:page])
end
```

Comment: Okay, I tried `@documents = Document.where(name: /#{@query}/i)` but same result. Doesn't recognize partial words.

Comment: @Gentsview I updated my answer with an alternative syntax.

Comment: I added an @ to the query, but now I get `no implicit conversion of nil into String`, I tried with `(:query)` then I get no error but no change from my previous solution.

Comment: @Gentsview, in that case, you'll need to add a check for `nil` in your assignment: `@query = params[:query] || ""`

Comment: that's right, I get rid of the error but no change in the result, partial words not recognized.

Comment: @Gentsview I updated the regular expression to include partial matches :)

Comment: I think I should change the set_documents or not?

Comment: @Gentsview, yes, you'll need to make the change in `set_documents`.  I updated my answer with an example replacement.

Comment: I updated the regex to be a little more lenient.  If that isn't working, verify that the `params[:query]` is getting passed correctly to the controller (Rails logs should give you a list of all params passed).  Also, maybe try removing the pagination and see if maybe that is causing a conflict.

Comment: `params[:query]` is getting passed like this `| STARTED | {"count"=>"documents", "query"=>{"user_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('3c0138ab171eaf08c356dd81'), "name"=>/.*casc.*/i, "_type"=>"UserDocument"}}` , tried removing pagination also didn't work.

Comment: Bingo!  There's the issue, `params[:query]` is a Hash.  Try updating your `set_query` method to `@query = (params[:query] || {}).fetch(:name)`

Comment: `@query = (params[:query] || {}).fetch("name", "")`

Comment: looks right but now I get: `undefined method 'fetch' for "casc":String`

Comment: That is a bit odd.  It means that your `query` param is providing inconsistent types (some cases a `Hash` and other cases a `String`).  I'd pinpoint what is causing that and try and provide a single behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Mongoid support regular expression in queries

```
User.where(:name => /.*anand.*/i )
```

Here **i** for non case sensitive matching.

or

```
search_term = params[:search_term]
User.where({:name => Regexp.new ("/.*"+search_term+".*/") })
```

you can write any regular expression in reg object

Comment: thanks for your answer but I get: `syntax error, unexpected ( arg, expecting '}'
...nt.where({:name => Regexp.new ("/.*"+@query+".*/") })`